# Python: look back n days rolling standard deviation

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question about dealing with the rolling standard deviation:

The data frame looks like this:

```
2010-01-20 05:00:00   -0.011
2010-01-20 05:02:00   -0.032
2010-01-20 05:02:00   -0.037
2010-01-20 05:04:00    0.001
2010-01-20 05:06:00    0.023
2010-01-20 05:06:00    0.011
2010-01-20 05:08:00    0.049
2010-01-20 05:10:00    0.102
....
2010-05-20 17:00:00    0.022
```

This is 2-min data from 5am to 5pm 
(The format of index 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss' is datestamp)

I want to calculate the 8-day look-back on the standard deviation. My intuition is to split the data frame into daily data set and then calculate the rolling standard deviation, but I don't know how to deal with these indexand i guess my methods may takes a lot of time to calculate. Thanks a lot for your help!

Finally, I would like the result like this:

```
2010-01-20   0.0
2010-01-21   0.0
2010-01-22   0.0
....
2010-01-26   0.0
2010-01-27   0.12
2010-01-28   0.02
2010-01-29   0.07
...
2010-05-20   0.10
```

Thank you for your help. @unutbu

Just found the problem in the data:
The data frame is not completely including the whole 2-min data.
For example:

```
2010-01-21 15:08:00    0.044
2010-01-22 05:10:00    0.102
```

The data ends at 15:08 on 2010-01-21 and start at 05:10:00 on 2010-01-22.
so setting window size with a constant may not fixed this problem.
Any suggestions? thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**If the time series has a constant frequency:**

You could compute the number of 2 second interals in 8 days:

```
window_size = pd.Timedelta('8D')/pd.Timedelta('2min')
```

and then use [`pd.rolling_std`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/computation.html#moving-rolling-statistics-moments) with `window=window_size`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

index = pd.date_range(start='2010-01-20 5:00', end='2010-05-20 17:00', freq='2T')
N = len(index)
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': np.random.random(N)}, index=index)
# the number of 2 second intervals in 8 days
window_size = pd.Timedelta('8D')/pd.Timedelta('2min')    # 5760.0

df['std'] = pd.rolling_std(df['val'], window=window_size)
print(df.tail())
```

yields

```
                          val       std
2010-05-20 16:52:00  0.768918  0.291137
2010-05-20 16:54:00  0.486348  0.291098
2010-05-20 16:56:00  0.679610  0.291099
2010-05-20 16:58:00  0.951798  0.291114
2010-05-20 17:00:00  0.059935  0.291109
```

To resample this time series so as to get one value per day, you could use the [`resample` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/timeseries.html#up-and-downsampling) and aggregate the values by taking the mean:

```
df['std'].resample('D', how='mean')
```

yields

```
...
2010-05-16    0.289019
2010-05-17    0.289988
2010-05-18    0.289713
2010-05-19    0.289269
2010-05-20    0.288890
Freq: D, Name: std, Length: 121
```

---

Above, we computed the rolling standard deviation and then resampled to a time
series with daily frequency.

If we were to resample the original data to daily frequency *first* and then
compute the rolling standard deviation then in general the result would be
different.

Note also that your data looks like it has quite a bit of variation within each
day, so resampling by taking the mean might (wrongly?) hide that variation.
So it is probably better to compute the std first.

---

**If the time series does not have a constant frequency:**

If you have enough memory, I think the easiest way to deal with this situation
is to use `asfreq` to expand the time series to one that has a constant
frequency.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

# make an example df
index = pd.date_range(start='2010-01-20 5:00', end='2010-05-20 17:00', freq='2T')
N = len(index)
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': np.random.random(N)}, index=index)
mask = np.random.randint(2, size=N).astype(bool)
df = df.loc[mask]

# expand the time series, filling in missing values with NaN
df = df.asfreq('2T', method=None)

# now we can use the constant-frequency solution
window_size = pd.Timedelta('8D')/pd.Timedelta('2min')    
df['std'] = pd.rolling_std(df['val'], window=window_size, min_periods=1)

result = df['std'].resample('D', how='mean')
print(result.head())
```

yields

```
2010-01-20    0.301834
2010-01-21    0.292505
2010-01-22    0.293897
2010-01-23    0.291018
2010-01-24    0.290444
Freq: D, Name: std, dtype: float64
```

The alternative to expanding the time series is to write code to compute the
correct sub-Series for each 8-day window.  While this is possible, the fact that
you would have to compute this for each row of the time series could make this
method very slow. Thus, I think the faster approach is to expand the time
series.

Comment: thank you for the comments. I think I got your idea.

Comment: Hi unutbu, I found the data doesn't include the whole 2-min data set. who should i set the dynamic window size or i should change another way to calcite this rolling standard deviation (I have updated my questions) do you have any suggestion for the new problem? thx.