# Forward rolling time windows in pandas.series

Tags: python, pandas, time

I want to use rolling time windows in pandas for forward looking windows. How would I do that?

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'t': ['2017-02-02 15:00:01',
                 '2017-02-02 15:00:02',
                 '2017-02-02 15:01:00',
                 '2017-02-02 15:03:05',
                 '2017-02-02 15:08:00'],
        'value': [1, 2, 3, 14, 5]})
data['t'] = data['t'].apply(pd.to_datetime)
data = data.set_index('t')

backward_max = data.rolling('300s').max() # yields [1, 2, 3, 14, 14]

forward_max = '???' # should yield [14, 14, 14, 14, 5]
```

Problem is that because of unequal time differences between observations, I cannot simply shift the result from the backward looking windows.

I could calculate fake time-stamps that go in reverse order and use backward time windows, as could be derived from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820292/how-to-use-pandas-rolling-functions-on-a-forward-looking-basis/22820689?noredirect=1#comment34813442_22820689), but I am almost certain there is a more elegant way.

**Edit**: Changed all timestamps to the same day and provide the following workaround code, as inelegant as it is.

```
data2 = data.reset_index()
data2['t2'] = max(data2['t']) - (data2['t'] - min(data2['t']))
data2 = data2.set_index('t2').sort_index()
forward_max = np.flip(data2.rolling('300s')['value'].max().values, axis=0)
```

Comment: why last one is 5 ? rather than 14 ?

Comment: The values for the points are [1, 2, 3, 14, 5]. A forward looking window starting at the last point only contains that one point, so the maximum of the values is the value of the last point, which is 5.

Comment: Time-based window shifts (or backwards rolling) is definitely a missing feature in pandas. Fake timestamps was the only way I could manage to do it efficiently (for a generic,  non-equispaced data).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, you could reverse the data frame/series, calculate your moving maximum, and reverse the results back. At least your example prediction can be achieved this way. (Tested with Pandas v2.0.2)

```
forward_max = data[::-1].rolling('300s').max()[::-1]
print(forward_max)
# Output:
#                      value
# t                         
# 2017-02-02 15:00:01   14.0
# 2017-02-02 15:00:02   14.0
# 2017-02-02 15:01:00   14.0
# 2017-02-02 15:03:05   14.0
# 2017-02-02 15:08:00    5.0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to this solution:
[Python: look back n days rolling standard deviation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29108785/python-look-back-n-days-rolling-standard-deviation)

However, it is still not a perfect solution. Somebody has raised an issue at Github, but it seems no one is working on it. Here is the link https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6772

Comment: As far as I understand the solution they propose, they have regular time intervals, which is not the case in my situation.

Answer (score -1):

A possible solution is to shift the rolling window aggregation

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There is no way to shift time series by time amount. Your answer is incorrect.